# How do I check a check box in a pdf template

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, pdf, itext

I would like to use data from a form and add to my pdf template.  I use the following for textfields...

```
PdfStamper formFiller = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
AcroFields formFields = formFiller.AcroFields;
formFields.SetField("Name", formData.Name);
```

How do I check a checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
formFields.SetField("checkBoxId", "Yes");
```

Comment: I found a question that had "checkBoxID", "true". This worked. Thanks!

Comment: The "check" value be customized.  With a check box, the only good way to check for the value is to call `AcroFields.getAppearanceStates()`.  "Off" is pretty self-explanitory, the other one, whatever that might be, is the "checked" value.